# How to pass data from controller to 'after' middleware in Laravel 6.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I have the following controller:

```
class Foo extends Controller
{
    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->middleware('bar', ['only' => ['store', 'update']]);
    }

    public function store ()
    {
        // some code to result $baz object (a model or null)
        // pass $baz to Bar middleware for further use
    }
}
```

and the following middleware that should be executed after controller code:

```
class Bar
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        // I need to use $baz here
        return $response;
    }
}
```

However, I can pass data from a normal middleware to controller using $request->request->add(['baz'=>123]) , but this is not working for 'after' middleware. I think the reason is that $request is not passed by reference in constructor/handle function to be updated for further use, only for consume. I have also tried Session::put() and Session::pull(), but for unclear reasons to me, it won't work (is returning null anytime). To return $baz in Foo.store() method thinking that Bar.handle() method would receive it as result returned, won't work (is returning a Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse object). I have searched around a lot, but google is returning me only normal(before) middleware case. How can I pass data from Controller to middleware with -after- execution in an elegant way?
I would prefer (if it is possible) a middleware approch for the sake of the question, not an alternative to middleware. Thanks!

Comment: side note: objects are always passed by reference

Comment: Thanks for mention. In that case, it should work...but it doesn't...

Comment: I will try to set a static property to involved model that should be updated in controller and accessed in middleware... but it seems to be a bad approch even if it would work